# panResponder keep capturing when there is two touches on screen

Tags: react-native, multi-touch, panresponder

I want when there are two touches on the screen panResponder to keep going and don't stop but after about half a second panResponder stops and begin to scroll
this is my code

```
import {View} from 'native-base';
import React, {Children, useMemo, useState} from 'react';
import {Animated, NativeTouchEvent, PanResponder} from 'react-native';
import {getDistance} from '../utils/functions';

interface Props {
  opacity: Animated.Value;
}

const PinchZoom: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  let initialXs: Array<number> = [];
  let initialYs: Array<number> = [];
  let currentXs: Array<number> = [];
  let currentYs: Array<number> = [];

  const resetAnimation = () => {
    Animated.spring(props.opacity, {
      toValue: props.opacity,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  const panResponder = useMemo(
    () =>
      PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (event) => {
          let touches = event.nativeEvent.touches;

          if (touches.length == 2) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        },
        onPanResponderStart: (initial_event, initial_gesture) => {
          let touches = initial_event.nativeEvent.touches;
          if (touches.length == 2) {
            initialXs = [];
            initialYs = [];
            initialXs.push(touches[0].locationX);
            initialXs.push(touches[1].locationX);
            initialYs.push(touches[0].locationY);
            initialYs.push(touches[1].locationY);
          }
        },
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
        onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {
          let touches = event.nativeEvent.touches;
          if (touches.length == 2) {
            currentXs = [];
            currentYs = [];
            currentXs.push(touches[0].locationX);
            currentXs.push(touches[1].locationX);
            currentYs.push(touches[0].locationY);
            currentYs.push(touches[1].locationY);
          }
          console.log('Xs', initialXs, currentXs);
          console.log('Ys', initialYs, currentYs);
        },
        onPanResponderRelease: (event, gesture) => {
          let touches = event.nativeEvent.touches;
          console.log('Xs', initialXs, currentXs);
          console.log('Ys', initialYs, currentYs);
          if (touches.length == 2) {
            console.log('Xs', initialXs, currentXs);
            console.log('Ys', initialYs, currentYs);
          }
        },
      }),
    [],
  );
  return (
    <Animated.View {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
      {props.children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default PinchZoom;
```

I want when the screen has two touches on it the panResponder starts and until there are two touches it continues and when there is one touch it stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I temporarily fixed this issue with the below code

```
import {Text} from 'native-base';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Animated, Dimensions, PanResponder} from 'react-native';
import {getDistance} from '../utils/functions';

const WINDOW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('screen').width;
const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('screen').height;

interface Props {
  distance: Animated.Value;
}

const PinchZoom: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  let initialXs: Array<number> = [];
  let initialYs: Array<number> = [];
  let currentXs: Array<number> = [];
  let currentYs: Array<number> = [];
  let distance = props.distance;
  let zIndex: number = 0;
  let initial_distance: number = 0;
  let current_distance: number = 0;

  const panResponder = useState(() =>
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gesture) => {
        let touches = event.nativeEvent.touches;
        if (gesture.numberActiveTouches == 2) {
          zIndex = 2;
          return true;
        } else {
          zIndex = 0;
          return false;
        }
      },
      onPanResponderStart: (initial_event, initial_gesture) => {
        let touches = initial_event.nativeEvent.touches;

        initialXs = [];
        initialYs = [];

        initialXs.push(touches[0].locationX);
        initialXs.push(touches[1].locationX);
        initialYs.push(touches[0].locationY);
        initialYs.push(touches[1].locationY);
      },
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        initialXs = initialXs;
        initialYs = initialYs;
        currentXs = currentXs;
        currentYs = currentYs;
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {
        let touches = event.nativeEvent.touches;

        if (touches.length == 2) {
          currentXs = [];
          currentYs = [];

          currentXs.push(touches[0].locationX);
          currentXs.push(touches[1].locationX);
          currentYs.push(touches[0].locationY);
          currentYs.push(touches[1].locationY);

          initial_distance = getDistance(
            initialXs[0],
            initialYs[0],
            initialXs[1],
            initialYs[1],
          );
          current_distance = getDistance(
            currentXs[0],
            currentYs[0],
            currentXs[1],
            currentYs[1],
          );
        }

        props.distance.setValue(initial_distance - current_distance);

      },
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        zIndex = 0;
      },
    }),
  )[0];
  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        width: WINDOW_WIDTH,
        height: WINDOW_HEIGHT,
        zIndex: zIndex,
      }}
      {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
      {props.children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default PinchZoom;
```

but if anybody has a better answer I appreciate for sharing it with me